How can I reset of the system printing dialog and what is it anyway?
I am using KDE Neon, based on Ubuntu 22.04 and I try to print via Chromium or Firefox. Both browsers have the option "Print via system dialog". When I try to print via Gimp, then a similar dialog opens. The print dialog of KDE applications looks totally different.
Sometimes the information in the printer system dialog does not reflect what I see in the CUPS setup. Some example issues I have encountered:

The printer list shows network printers, while CUPS does not
The printer list shows a printer I recently removed, while CUPS does not
I updated a standard printer setting in CUPS, this seemed to have an effect after some hours but not immediately
I updated a PPD file and added more page formats. The new pages are shown in CUPS but not in the "system print dialog". This is the same after 12h and consistent across Firefox, Chromium and Gimp. So I assume that the "dialog" somewhere stores information that it received for indefinite time

I searched for "System printer dialog" but I cannot find anything. I found hints about a "Common printing dialog" project, but this seems outdated.
How can I reset the state of the printer dialog?
Is there a way to disable all caching in relation to that dialog?
What is the system printer dialog? Where is the source code and where is it documented?

Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a KDE/Neon forum.    FYI:   KDE Neon does share a number of support options common with Kubuntu, alas this is not one of them with Neon off-topic here

@guiverc: I assume the behaviour does not relate to KDE Neon. I will make an experiment with normal Ubuntu and update the question.
